# Forcing absolute <img> src links in the RSS feed

Tags: images, rss, html, feed

We are using relative image URLs in the post's HTML code. Looks like relative  src links break on many RSS readers.

By default, Wordpress does not seem to prepare post's HTML for feed too much. Does there exist any solution for post-processing the feed URL and encoring all links and src attributes to be absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative URLs are considered bad practice in WP, because of such issues and that they can be much more complex to migrate.

Basic approach to fixing this (not counting changing to absolute URLs everywhere) would be to filter `the_content`, while checking for `is_feed()`, and adjust links on the fly.

Comment: In the case of absolute URLs how are you going to migrate? You need to rewrite absolute URLs in every post?

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa yes. And this is technically easier than to detect and rewrite relative URLs when go up/down a level or something like that.